# How to get whether richtextbox last word is BringIntoView(shown) or not in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, frameworkelement

i am working in wpf,i have a richtextbox with some contents.if the contents are exceeded to richtextbox i want to hide bottom border.if the content within the richtextbox i want to show the bottom border.Now i am using the below code to bring the exceeded content to view in richtextbox.

```
 FrameworkContentElement fce = (startPos.Parent as FrameworkContentElement);
            if (fce != null)
            {
                fce.BringIntoView();
            }
```

But i want to display the bottom border,once the last word shown in that richtextbox.How to achieve this?

**Note:** I already known how to show bottom border dynamically.but i want to know last word are displayed within the richtextbox or not?

Regards
Arjun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can provide you with a method to check whether the upper left corner of a character is visible or not.
Create a class library `Tools` with the following content:

```
public class ToolsRtb
{
    public static bool PositionVisibleIs(RichTextBox rtb, TextPointer pos)
    {
        // Rectangle around the character to check
        Rect r = pos.GetCharacterRect(LogicalDirection.Forward);

        // Upper left corner of the rectangle ...
        Point upperLeftCorner = r.Location;

        HitTestResult result = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(rtb, upperLeftCorner);

        // ... is visible?
        if (result != null)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }   
}
```

Note that `PositionVisibleIs(...)` is a static method and not dedicated to a specific object.
In the code behind file of the window which contains your `RichTextBox` use the method like this:

```
// Is the last character of the current document visible?
if (ToolsRtb.PositionVisibleIs(rtb, rtb.Document.ContentEnd) == true)
{
    ...
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @ Pollitzer : its working fine.but after one panning,i want to clear current content and load new content,at that time that Rect value same as previous.but i want to clear it and act like same as before panning.I mean Once the result value is comes null i do some panning after i reload data the result value also null.how to clear that value?

Comment: After clearing the `RichTextBox` and loading new content you must call PositionVisibleIs(rtb, rtb.Document.ContentEnd) again because last visible position will be different from content to content, depending on font size, upper case / lower case, bold / normal etc.

Comment: @ Pollitzer : Thanks.But PositionVIsibles come from which class?Can u show in code?

Comment: @ Pollitzer : Can u look at this link.U got what i exactly need. [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34783272/clear-pageup-pagedown-panning-values-after-clear-and-reload-content-in-wpf-richt)