# Set current caretPosition in RichTextBox viewport end?

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I already used the below code.  It moves current caret position in viewport top.

```
FrameworkContentElement fce = (tpNextLine2.Parent as FrameworkContentElement);
if (fce != null)
{
    fce.BringIntoView();
}
```

I want to move current caretposition textpointer in richtextbox viewport end using WPF.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to change current caret position but scroll the WPF RichTextBox to move this position to the bottom of the visible area, you can use this code:

```
Rect rc = rtb.CaretPosition.GetCharacterRect(LogicalDirection.Forward);
rtb.ScrollToVerticalOffset(rc.Bottom + rtb.VerticalOffset - rtb.ViewportHeight);
```

Comment: @ Fratyx : Thank u. its like what i want.but how to check currentcaretposition is in viewport or not? Because after one pageup,each line scrolled.so i think,once i call your codes after check whether the current caret position is not in the viewport.

Comment: @arjun sanju: You can check if a position is visible or not by [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34691469/3135228).

Comment: @ Crawumbo : The above same logic, how to get rc.Top in view?

Comment: @arjun sanju: You can combine CaretPosition.GetCharacterRect, VerticalOffset, ViewportHeight and ExtentHeight to all  possible calculations. E.g. if the CaretPosition (i.e. CharacterRect) is negative, the Caret is above the Viewport. If the position is bigger than ViewportHeight, the Caret is below the Viewport.

Comment: @ Fratyx : Can u show in the code for Rect caretposition  in top of the viewport?

Comment: `rtb.ScrollToVerticalOffset(rc.Top + rtb.VerticalOffset);`

Comment: @Fratyx : Sorry.not working.it also panning after away from viewport.I mean,read one word from hidden area.then only page up happened.

Comment: @arjun sanju: Sorry, don't understand your intention.

Comment: @ Fratyx : Actually BringIntoView() working once move to invisible area firstword then only page down happened,same as our code rtb.ScrollToVerticalOffset(rc.Top + rtb.VerticalOffset); working.but i want whether the caretposition try to move invisible area,need to show that line in top of the viewport.Got my point?

Comment: @arjun sanju: So you want to call this piece of code after the user scrolled the viewport or changed the caret position?

Comment: @ Fratyx : Yes.Your rtb.ScrollToVerticalOffset(rc.Top + rtb.VerticalOffset); is working.but only works when  the caretposition moved under viewport.i mean the first word of the line not shown,once moved to the second word then only the panning happened.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
RichTextBox1.Select(RichTextBox1.Text.Length - 1, 0);

RichTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();
```

Comment: Unfortunately this just works in Windows.Forms, not in WPF